# C# Perfom Image Search with WInodws.Forms GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I've built a simple application that links to the url of image searches pertaining to the content of the listbox to the right of the browser window as follows:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ar02lrNB2lmbm0g7RF3RY6-T6NHz

I've accomplished this with several if statements that refer to the index of my list box, what I am hoping for is a more eloquent solution to this problem. As of now each new search term must be hard coded and refers to the same image search, is there by chance a way that the text in the listbox could be read and an image search performed instead of the solution I have? I mean it works but there has to be a better way.

```
 public partial class frmCatSearch : Form
    {
        public frmCatSearch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Event Handler for the button
            // Pop up a message box with the current time/date
            MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Navigates to a google image search depending on the selected 
        /// listbox item. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lblArtimus.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                artimusBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search");
            }
            if (lblArtimus.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                artimusBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search");
            }
            if (lblArtimus.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                artimusBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search");
            }

            //else
            //{
            //    artimusBrowser.Navigate("https://images.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl");
            //}
        }

        //Code purposefully omitted 

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads objects into listbox
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add some cats
            lblArtimus.Items.Add("Alley Cat");
            lblArtimus.Items.Add("American Bobtail");
            lblArtimus.Items.Add("Burmilla");
            lblArtimus.Items.Add("Cornish Rex");
            lblArtimus.Items.Add("Devon Rex");
            lblArtimus.Items.Add("Maine Coon");
            lblArtimus.Items.Add("Chesire");

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to get the text from the selected item? If so, will this do:

```
string searchText = this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Then just search for the value of searchText.

I may be missing what you're trying to achieve here though.

Comment: That would be part of the answer, I'd need the text within the listBox in order to do an image search, but what I would like to do if possible is perform a new search each time an item is clicked rather than referencing an old search.